# How to display specific data in jasper Report?

Tags: php, postgresql, jasper-reports

I am beginner in Jasper report, i have created a jasper report table which contains more than one million data. I want to display the jasper report as per the user need.I have database in PostgreSQL named "Banke" and table named Arsenic_Test.i want to make a choice for my user to select the data, For example I have 3 options for the user to select "data with value X<50, X=50 or X>50. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parameters in your queries. 
For example your query can look like

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE X < $P{value_lower}
```

Ofcourse you have to prepare more complicated query. I think you need a 3 parameters - one for `<`, another for `=` and the last for `>` and check them if they are not nulls in where cluase (because you can't provide an operation with parameter but just only the value). For example you can use something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table 
WHERE ($P{value_lower} is not null and X < $P{value_lower})
OR ($P{value_equal} is not null and X = $P{value_equal})
OR ($P{value_higher} is not null and X > $P{value_higher})
```

If you need more information about using parameters then look at for example this [tutorial](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-report-parameters) or if you want to learn more about connect JR with your site then you should look at http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/php-client-sample-code (specially at **Reporting Services** section). For example if you want know how to provide inputs then you should look at this example

```
$controls = array(
   'Country_multi_select' => array('USA', 'Mexico'),
   'Cascading_state_multi_select' => array('CA', 'OR')
   );


$report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/samples/Cascading_multi_select_report', 'html', null, null, $controls);

echo $report;
```

Comment: thank u for your assistance but i already have that query in PostgreSQL but how to implement that query in Jasper report? i have html form for user inputs but got stuck how to link those input button to that of jasper report data .the user inputs are in simple HTML form but got stuck how to link those given inputs to that of jasper report server?

Comment: @AarzeenKharel I've add more information that probably suit your needs. If not then please provide more information about problem with it or add new question with new problem.